# Spider Model Collision Response

Tags: artificial-intelligence, processing, vector-graphics

I am working with a tweak of the [legs](http://openprocessing.org/sketch/12684) demo from open proccessing and attempting a simple evasion AI for my generated spider.  The goal is for the AI spider to evade the player controlled one.  My code:

```
float distance = sqrt((c2.currentX - creature.currentX)*(c2.currentX - creature.currentX)+(c2.currentY-creature.currentY)*(c2.currentY-creature.currentY));      

if (distance < c2.radius){
    c2.heading = atan(c2.heading);
    if(millis() - time >= wait){
        time = millis();
    }
}
```

This is located in my updated draw() andI have gotten a response from the AI, but the response is either the AI stands still or shoots off the screen. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the AI spider to move directly away from the player, then calculating your heading like this may work better (although it's hard to say for sure without seeing all of your code):

```
c2.heading = atan2(c2.currentY - creature.currentY, c2.currentX - creature.currentX);
```

What that does is calculate the angle from `creature` to `c2`, and uses that as the heading. The result should be that `c2` will move directly away from `creature`.

(I'm assuming that `c2` is the AI spider here!)

As a side note, passing an angle into `atan` isn't likely to give you anything useful. It's designed to accept a trigonometric ratio as the parameter. `atan2` is very similar, but it's often more useful as it does a little more of the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, I will work on implementing these suggestions.